# get the string value of BackColor

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a radio buttons with a particular `backcolor` property as `green`, `white` and `yellow`

I need to get that color value off the `backcolor` property but what I get is `System.Drawing.Color` as the output for `radControl.BackColor.ToString`

How do I get the color in the `backcolor` property of the control?

```
Private Sub radControl_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles radControl.CheckedChanged
    lbkLblClearColor.Text = radControl.BackColor.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: the code you posted is correct

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `Name` property of the color.

Eg. `radControl.BackColor.Name`

If the above doesn't work, please consider posting sample code snippet.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not work in VS 2008. It retuned an error that `name` is not a member of `System.Drawing.Color`

Comment: @JeromeAdmana : The [**`Color.Name` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.name(v=vs.110).aspx) has existed since the `Color` structure was introduced in .NET 1.1 (the VS version is irrelevant), so the code definitely should work.